# Segmentation fault when calling a function with reading file struct

Tags: c, file, struct, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct MATIERE 
{
    int reference;
    char libelle[15];
    unsigned int coefficient;
}Matiere;

Matiere matiere;

int recherche_matiere(int beta)
{
    FILE *fic;
    fic = fopen("matieres.csv", "r");
    
    do
   { 
        fscanf(fic, "%d %14s %d",  &matiere.reference,matiere.libelle,&matiere.coefficient);
        if (matiere.reference == beta)
        {
           printf("Cette matière existe bien dans notre base de donnèes \n");
           return 1;
           fclose(fic);
        }
    }while(!feof(fic));
    
    fclose(fic);
    printf("Cette matière est une nouveauté \n");
    return 0;
    
}

void ajout_matiere()
{
    FILE *fic;
    int num_matiere;
    
    init:
    printf("Veuillez ajouter la référence de la matière à ajouter : \n");
    scanf("%d",&num_matiere);
    
    if (recherche_matiere(num_matiere) == 1)
    {
       printf("La référence choisie est réservée à une autre matiere : \n");
       goto init;
    }
    
    else
    {
        printf("Processus d'ajout d'une matière en cours : \n"); 
       
        fic = fopen("matiere.csv", "a");
        
        matiere.reference = num_matiere;
        printf("Veuillez renseigner le libelle de la matière :\n");
        scanf("%14s", matiere.libelle);
        printf("Enter le coefficient de la matière :\n");
        scanf("%d", &matiere.coefficient);
            
        fprintf(fic, "%d %s %d\n", matiere.reference,matiere.libelle,matiere.coefficient);
        
        fclose(fic);
        printf("L'ajout s'est fait avec succès \n");
    }
    

}

int main()
{
    ajout_matiere();
    return 0;

}
```

I would like to manage the subjects of a class with the options: add a subject, modify a subject, delete a class.
first of all I defined a structure type with the different fields before declaring my variables, all in order to store the information in a file.
Then I split my code into several functions in order to have more consistency but above all readability
But when the function is called in the program, I am returned a ** segmentation fault (core dumped) ** and that for all other functions even though I only posted one of these functions

Comment: Do your `fopen` calls succeed?  If you have a core dump, have you analyzed it to see exactly where the segfault occurs?

Comment: can you paste matieres.csv?

Comment: You have an `fclose` call immediately following an `return`.  Do you understand that the `fclose` call is unreachable, dead code, which the optimizer will likely delete?  Either move it *before* the `return`, or else just delete it.

Comment: One major problem is that you're ignoring the return value from `scanf`, and are just assuming there are no errors in your file and that all expected fields were read.  Also, checking `feof` the way you are isn't going to do what you want it to do.  You're going to end up with a return value of `-1` from `scanf`, which you're failing to catch, before `feof` returns true.

Comment: @alinsoar
Indeed matieres.csv is not generated

Comment: There's also no need to use `goto` in this code.  All it does is obscure the control structure.  Just replace it with an ordinary loop.

Comment: It looks like you've got plenty to fix at this point, including your broken `scanf` loop which needs to be fixed before your code will work.

Comment: @TomKarzes  I tried to remove the value returned after fclose but core dumped still persists.I am a new c programmer so if you can show me how I should proceed concretely it would help me a lot!  Thanks in advance

Comment: Your biggest problem is the `fscanf` loop.  Assign the return value to a variable.  It should be one of two values:  3, if it successfully read a line, or EOF if you're at the end of the file.  If it's 3, keep going.  If it's EOF, exit the loop.  If it's any other value, print an error message and exit.  Remove the `feof` call entirely.  It will only cause problems.

Comment: @TomKarzes  Exactly, It works now!. I think fscanf and feof were not appropriate for solving this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).